# Show that $x^4-2$ is the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt[4]{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do I prove that there is no other polynomial $p$ which is normed and of less or equal degree than $4$ which satisfies the equation $p(\sqrt[4]{2})=0$ ?

Is there some sort of algorithm one can use to solve those kind of questions?

I did not cover any galois theory. We just heared what algebraic and trancendent is

Comment: Hint: the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[4]{2}$ is an irreducible divisor over $\mathbb{Q}$ of $X^4-2$. Can you factor this polynomial over -$\mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 0):

Our problem is equivalent to showing that $1,\sqrt[4]{2}, \sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt[4]8$ are linearly independent. Assume the contrary, then we have rational $a,b,c$ for which:
$$\sqrt[4] 8 = a\sqrt2+b\sqrt[4]2+c$$
Raising the whole equation to the power of $4$ gives a value in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]2,\sqrt2]$. Hence, we would see that the values of $\sqrt[4]2, \sqrt2$ and $1$ are not linearly independent either. Putting $\sqrt[4]2$ in the LHS and repeating the process again will imply that $\sqrt2$ and $1$ are not linearly independent i.e. $\sqrt 2$ is rational, which is a contradiction.

Now, since $1,\sqrt[4]2,\sqrt2,\sqrt[4]8$ are linearly independent. There does not exist a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $3$ with $\sqrt[4]2$ as a root. Hence, the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[4]2$ has degree $4$. Moreover, the polynomial $x^4-2$ is also unique upto scaling (else, you can use two minimal polynomials of degree $4$ and subtract them after scaling them appropriately and get a smaller minimal polynomial).